# IIS username and password required

Tags: windows-xp, iis-7

I've just installed IIS 7.0 Manager on Windows XP Professional.

On startup, it prompted me for a username and password. However, I do not know the username and password for it as I'm using it on my school's computer.

Do I have to contact the administrator for the username & password or is it common for all IIs 7.0 on Windows XP Professional?

Answer (score 0):

IIS Manager 7.0 for XP only works for connecting to a Remote IIS 7+ running in Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2. That means that you do need to know the remote server, the username and password, as well as the site name that you will be connecting to (unless you connect as server administrator).

If your goal is to use IIS locally you have only two options:

1. Use IIS 5.1 which is included in Windows XP - however it is very old and does not support some of the cool new features
2. Use [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) to use IIS Developer Express which is based on IIS 7.5